# How to avoid inserting duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql, hbase, etl, talend

I am running my Talend job in Windows Task Scheduler with interval of 15 minutes. The process is like exporting data from HBase into PostgreSQL. So when I'm running the task, the 2nd schedule reinserts the records again from 1st schedule and so on.

```
HBase schema -> id int, name string
PostgreSQL schema -> id int, name varchar(100),created index on (id) column.
```

Example :

schedule insert

```
1st schedule       2nd schedule

`id``name`          `id` `name`

1    abcd            4    bbbb
2    efgh            5    cccc
3    hjkl            6    eeee

my output in POSTGRES :     EXPECTED output :
afer scheduling 

id   name                   id      name

1    abcd                    1      abcd
2    efgh                    2      efgh
3    hjkl                    3      hjkl
1    abcd                    4      bbbb
2    efgh                    5      cccc
3    hjkl                    6      eeee
4    bbbb
5    cccc
6    eeee
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Postgres version? Please add schema of table you are importing into. Once data is imported why is not cleared from schedule task? Or why is not ignored when pulling from Hbase?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  using PostgreSQL 10.12 version.

Comment: I tried several times, but could't find any solution. I am not sure where the change has to be done either in database or in talend

Comment: Tried what? What is the table schema?  Have you looked at [On Conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)"The optional ON CONFLICT clause specifies an alternative action to raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error."

Comment: Hbase table schema : id int , name string

Comment: The Postgres table? Please complete schema, including indexes, Primary Key, etc. Also add this information(including Hbase schema) to your question so folks don't have to work through the comments to get it.

Comment: There is nothing to do with Postgres table. Is should be handled in Talend. @pavithra, if am not wrong , in the first scheduled you are getting the records and in the second schedule you are getting the records along with the data in first schedule. Correct?

Comment: @JimMacaulay yes you are right !

Comment: I have provided you the solution below, let me know if you are still stuck. Will help you on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your postgresql target table as a look up and check for the existing data.
Your flow should be as below,

```
source --> Expression --> Target

            Lookup(to check existing data)
```

Your flow should be as below,

[image]

Let me know if you need more assistance on this. This is a quick and easy task

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work out. Should I change anything in tMap ??

Comment: Do you have team weaver, so that i can help you?

Comment: Hey thanks ! but actually it worked fine without look up, when I added primary key on one of the columns.

Comment: Then you might be using Update Insert functionality correct?

Comment: How does look up work in other case? will that require primary key on one column?

Comment: But its not a correct way of design. I will cause lots of performance issues. It will update each record again which is incorrect way and provides you lots of performance issues. You have to look up the target table and pass only the new records or restrict the existing records in the source itself

Comment: Look up does not require any primary key

Comment: Hope look up helped you